# OSX port of Mono.Zeroconf

Tags: macos, mono, zeroconf

I was trying to get MZClient to run on OSX 10.7.3 and can't get past the ProviderFactory module not finding any acceptable entries in the /bin directory.  I've experimented with trying to hard code the file name, but haven't made it work yet.  Any suggestions on how to get this going?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.Bonjour.dll in your application directory and also make sure you have Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.Bonjour.dll.config in there with the following contents:

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="dnssd.dll" target="libc.dylib" os="osx" />
</configuration>
```

It's that .config file that took me awhile to figure out.