# Mono.ZeroConf Mac, No Zeroconf providers can be found

Tags: macos, mono, bonjour, zeroconf

I have recently built a bonjour system using Mono.ZeroConf on Windows and wanted to try and convert it to mac. I am running into issues with this error:

No Zeroconf providers could be found or initialized. Necessary daemon may not be running.

I have tried the sample code provided by http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf and have tried using my own dlls with my own project that were built on the Windows machine. Both run into the same errors.

Now to resolve this on Windows, I installed Bonjour Print Services. I can't see an equivalent for Mac and imagined that the latest version of Bonjour should be installed anyway.

Was just wondering if anybody had any ideas why this error could occur?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution on this other StackOverflow thread:

[OSX port of Mono.Zeroconf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421271/osx-port-of-mono-zeroconf)

Best regards.